# Find the UTF-8 Length of a given codepoint

Tags: c++, performance, utf-8

A codepoint in UTF-8 can be represented by one to four bytes. Given a codepoint, I need to determine the length (in bytes) of the codepoint if it were represented in UTF-8. For this, I've written the following function:

```cpp
char utf8_char_size(uint32_t ch) {
    if (ch < 0x80) return 1;
    if (ch < 0x800) return 2;
    if (ch < 0x10000) return 3;
    return 4;
}
```

It works, and it's pretty simple to understand. However, I'm afraid that branching three times per codepoint could lead to a large amount of branch mispredictions which would slow my code down tremendously. Is this code fine?

Comment: "slow my code down tremendously" - why? sure, branch mispredictions can be bad, but there are *many* other things that can blow you out of the water. Why do you think you need to optimize this tiny function first?

Comment: If you truly need a branchless approach, you could do this with only bitwise operators, which shouldn't cause branching. Otherwise you can use ternary and/or boolean operators, which may or may not cause branching depending on architecture

Comment: @Dannnno Could you show it with only bitwise operators?

Comment: @superbrain I have no interest in writing it out, because it'll be painful. General idea will look like this: (1) identify if there is a bit set above 0x10000 (2) identify if there is a bit set between 0x800 and 0x10000 (3) identify if there is a bit set between 0x80 and 0x800. (4) Sum those 3 numbers and add 1

Comment: off the top, I figure you'd do a bitshift down into your range, then |= each bit in the range until you have either a 1 or a 0.

Comment: @Dannnno So you'd explicitly look at each bit separately? Then I suspect `return 1 + (ch >= 0x80) + (ch >= 0x800) + (ch >= 0x10000)` would be faster...

Comment: Almost certainly; but the request was for bitwise only

Comment: Another possibility: `return ffs(ch)["\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\3\3\3\3\3\3\3\3\3\4\4\4\4\4\4\4\4"];` or perhaps: `return 1 + ((0xffffaaaa95554000 >> 2 * ffs(ch)) & 2)`

Comment: [`ffs()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ffs.3.html) is POSIX, and indeed not in the standard library. With C++20 you could use [`std::countl_zero()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_zero) to similar effect.

Comment: @G.Sliepen im benchmarking all of our solutions, so far yours is the fastest.

Comment: @AryanParekh Please do create an answer containing the various alternative solutions and the benchmark results.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yes Il do that, Let more solutions come in :)

Comment: @G.Sliepen Would you happen to know how to call `ffs` in MSVC? I see `_BitScanForward` but it takes a 64-bit number,

Comment: You can replace `ffs()` with `31 - std::countl_zero()`. GCC recognizes this pattern, and on x86_64 it will use the `bsr` instruction. However, Clang uses `lzcnt` and has to subtract the result from 31 somehow. So changing the functions to have the string and constant reversed might be faster with Clang. Different CPU architectures also have different ways to report the first set bit. As for `ffs()` on MSVC: use [_BitScanReverse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/bitscanreverse-bitscanreverse64?view=msvc-160).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117031/discussion-between-aryan-parekh-and-g-sliepen).

Answer (score 5):

Since C++ types are declared in the `std` namespace, we should be using `std::uint32_t` here - or better still `char32_t` - rather than non-portably relying on the implementation also declaring `uint32_t` in the global namespace.

Returning a `char` seems suspect, as we'll be returning a small integer value rather than a meaningful *character* code.

Other than that, the implementation is clear enough.  We might rephrase as

```
return 1
     + (ch >= 0x80)
     + (ch >= 0x800)
     + (ch >= 0x10000);
```

in the hope of reducing branches, but I'm not sure a decent optimising compiler would produce different code.  You should inspect and profile the generated object code before choosing to make the code less clear.

An alternative on platforms with a quick `std::countl_zero()` would be to use that value in a `switch` or to index an array of resultant lengths.  Again, a good optimiser should do this for you with the clear, readable source of the question.

Comment: Unlike `std::uint32_t`, `char32_t` is a built in type, not a typedef defined in `std` namespace

Comment: Quite right - fixed.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use Appropriate Types

The type of a UCS-4 codepoint should be `char32_t`.  For a small unsigned value, I would use `uint8_t`—especially if you’re also going to be working with a UTF-8 string of 8-bit characters.

In practice, this doesn’t matter much, because the types implicitly convert to each other when you use this function in an expression.

#### Use `constexpr` and `noexcept`

Modern compilers seem to be able to optimize a function this simple without being told, but this will protect maintainers from making some changes that will slow things down.

#### Avoid `if`

Toby Speight already gave you a good branchless implementation.  The approach I more often use for code that I want to auto-vectorize, because it’s more general, is this:

```cpp
constexpr uint8_t utf8_unit_size(const char32_t c) noexcept
{
    return (c < 0x80)    ? 1 :
           (c < 0x800)   ? 2 :
           (c < 0x10000) ? 3 :
                           4;
}
```

In a case like this, it will produce the same code as yours, but the great advantage of it is that the compiler will only let you use `constexpr` expressions of the same type in each branch.  And modern compilers are very good at optimizing code that follows those rules.

In practice, Toby Speight’s version does optimize better on modern optimizing compilers.  Using the flags `-std=C++20 -O3 -march=x86-64-v4`, Clang 16 compiles the version using addition to

```
        mov     edx, dword ptr [rax]
        xor     esi, esi
        cmp     edx, 127
        seta    sil
        cmp     edx, 2048
        sbb     rbx, -1
        add     rbx, rsi
        cmp     edx, 65536
        sbb     rbx, -1
        inc     rbx
```

The optimizer is turning the additions into subtract-with borrow instructions (`sbb rbx, -1`), which add the carry flag to the second operand.  When the `cmp` instruction sets the carry, it therefore subtracts (-1 + 1), the same as adding 0.  When the `cmp` instruction clears the carry, it subtracts (-1 + 0), the same as adding 1.

However, the code using either `if` statements or ternary `?` expressions produces conditional branches on GCC 13 or Clang 16.  ICX 2022 compiles them into conditional moves.  The version that adds relational expressions produces branchless code, although it still depends on the flags.  So it should be slightly better than `if`/`else` on ICX, but significantly better on GCC or Clang.

In practice, you are likely to be working with a lot of codepoints in the same range, so the branch predictor would probably figure out quickly that (for example) most codepoints it’s seeing are ASCII, a few are in Latin Extended, and almost none are outside the BMP.

#### Benchmark Performance in Loops

The only way this function will ever be performance-critical is if you use it in a loop.  Which is how it would normally be used: you run functions like this on strings, not isolated characters.

Here is a more realistic example of how you would be using this: a template function to calculate the length of the UTF-8 conversion of any container holding a type compatible with `char32_t`:  In other words, it works on anything wide-stringy: a `std::u32string`, a `std::vector<uint32_t>`, or for that matter, it would work on an `unsigned char[BUF_SIZE]` holding ISO-8859-1 data.

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // transform_reduce
#include <concepts>  // convertible_to
#include <numeric>   // plus
#include <ranges>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string>

char utf8_char_size(uint32_t ch) {
    if (ch < 0x80) return 1;
    if (ch < 0x800) return 2;
    if (ch < 0x10000) return 3;
    return 4;
}


// Adaptation of Toby Speight's code:
constexpr uint8_t utf8_unit_size(const char32_t c) noexcept
{
    return 1U
         + (c >= 0x80)
         + (c >= 0x800)
         + (c >= 0x10000);
}


template<class T>
    requires std::ranges::input_range<T> &&
             std::convertible_to<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>, char32_t>
constexpr size_t utf8_str_size(const T& s) noexcept
{
    return std::transform_reduce(
        std::ranges::begin(s),
        std::ranges::end(s),
        (size_t)0,
        std::plus<size_t>{},
        utf8_unit_size
    );
}
```

Using either your helper function or Toby Speight’s, modern compilers turn this into highly-optimized, vectorized code.  You could even, with little additional effort, add a parallel execution policy.  Here is the inner loop of the version calling your function, exactly as you wrote it, on GCC 16 with `-std=c++20 -O3 -march=x86-64-v4`:

```
.LBB1_8:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovdqu ymm15, ymmword ptr [r9 - 192]
        vmovdqu64       ymm22, ymmword ptr [r9 - 160]
        vmovdqu ymm0, ymmword ptr [r9 - 128]
        vmovdqu64       ymm23, ymmword ptr [r9 - 96]
        vmovdqa64       ymm31, ymm15
        vmovdqa xmm1, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_0] # xmm1 = [0,4,8,12]
        vmovdqa64       ymm21, ymm1
        vpermt2d        ymm31, ymm1, ymm22
        vmovdqa64       ymm16, ymm0
        vpermt2d        ymm16, ymm1, ymm23
        vmovdqu ymm1, ymmword ptr [r9 - 32]
        vmovdqu ymm13, ymmword ptr [r9 - 64]
        vmovdqa64       ymm29, ymm13
        vmovdqu ymm2, ymmword ptr [r9 + 32]
        vmovdqu ymm14, ymmword ptr [r9]
        vpermt2d        ymm29, ymm21, ymm1
        vmovdqa64       ymm30, ymm14
        vpermt2d        ymm30, ymm21, ymm2
        vmovdqa64       ymm25, ymm15
        vmovdqa64       xmm21, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_1] # xmm21 = [1,5,9,13]
        vpermt2d        ymm25, ymm21, ymm22
        vmovdqa64       ymm26, ymm0
        vpermt2d        ymm26, ymm21, ymm23
        vmovdqa64       ymm27, ymm13
        vpermt2d        ymm27, ymm21, ymm1
        vmovdqa64       ymm28, ymm14
        vpermt2d        ymm28, ymm21, ymm2
        vmovdqa64       ymm21, ymm15
        vmovdqa xmm3, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_2] # xmm3 = [2,6,10,14]
        vpermt2d        ymm21, ymm3, ymm22
        vmovdqa xmm12, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_3] # xmm12 = [3,7,11,15]
        vpermt2d        ymm15, ymm12, ymm22
        vmovdqa64       ymm24, ymm0
        vpermt2d        ymm24, ymm3, ymm23
        vpermt2d        ymm0, ymm12, ymm23
        vmovdqa64       ymm22, ymm13
        vpermt2d        ymm22, ymm3, ymm1
        vpermt2d        ymm13, ymm12, ymm1
        vmovdqa64       ymm23, ymm14
        vpermt2d        ymm23, ymm3, ymm2
        vpermt2d        ymm14, ymm12, ymm2
        vpcmpltud       k2, xmm31, xmm4
        vpcmpltud       k1, xmm16, xmm4
        kmovw   word ptr [rsp - 26], k1         # 2-byte Spill
        vpcmpltud       k4, xmm31, xmm5
        vpcmpltud       k3, xmm16, xmm5
        vpaddd  xmm1, xmm31, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k5, xmm1, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm1 {k4}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddd  xmm2, xmm16, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k4, xmm2, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm2 {k5}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm1 {k2}, ymm2
        vpcmpltud       k2, xmm29, xmm4
        vpcmpltud       k5, xmm30, xmm4
        vpcmpltud       k6, xmm29, xmm5
        vpcmpltud       k7, xmm30, xmm5
        vpaddd  xmm2, xmm29, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k1, xmm2, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm2 {k3}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddd  xmm16, xmm30, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k3, xmm16, xmm9
        vpaddq  ymm30, ymm1, ymm17
        vpblendmq       ymm1 {k4}, ymm11, ymm10
        kmovw   k4, word ptr [rsp - 26]         # 2-byte Reload
        vmovdqa64       ymm2 {k4}, ymm1
        vpblendmq       ymm1 {k6}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddq  ymm29, ymm2, ymm18
        vpblendmq       ymm2 {k1}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm1 {k2}, ymm2
        vpblendmq       ymm2 {k7}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddq  ymm18, ymm1, ymm19
        vpblendmq       ymm1 {k3}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm2 {k5}, ymm1
        vpaddq  ymm17, ymm2, ymm20
        vpcmpltud       k4, xmm25, xmm4
        vpcmpltud       k3, xmm26, xmm4
        vpcmpltud       k2, xmm27, xmm4
        vpcmpltud       k1, xmm28, xmm4
        kmovw   word ptr [rsp - 26], k1         # 2-byte Spill
        vpcmpltud       k5, xmm25, xmm5
        vpcmpltud       k6, xmm26, xmm5
        vpcmpltud       k7, xmm27, xmm5
        vpcmpltud       k1, xmm28, xmm5
        vpblendmq       ymm1 {k5}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddd  xmm2, xmm25, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k5, xmm2, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm2 {k6}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddd  xmm16, xmm26, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k6, xmm16, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm16 {k7}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddd  xmm19, xmm27, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k7, xmm19, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm19 {k1}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddd  xmm20, xmm28, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k1, xmm20, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm20 {k5}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm1 {k4}, ymm20
        vpblendmq       ymm20 {k6}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm2 {k3}, ymm20
        vpblendmq       ymm20 {k7}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm16 {k2}, ymm20
        vpblendmq       ymm20 {k1}, ymm11, ymm10
        kmovw   k1, word ptr [rsp - 26]         # 2-byte Reload
        vmovdqa64       ymm19 {k1}, ymm20
        vpcmpltud       k2, xmm21, xmm4
        vpcmpltud       k1, xmm24, xmm4
        kmovw   word ptr [rsp - 26], k1         # 2-byte Spill
        vpcmpltud       k4, xmm21, xmm5
        vpcmpltud       k3, xmm24, xmm5
        vpaddd  xmm20, xmm21, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k5, xmm20, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm20 {k4}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddd  xmm21, xmm24, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k4, xmm21, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm21 {k5}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm20 {k2}, ymm21
        vpcmpltud       k2, xmm22, xmm4
        vpcmpltud       k5, xmm23, xmm4
        vpcmpltud       k6, xmm22, xmm5
        vpcmpltud       k7, xmm23, xmm5
        vpaddd  xmm21, xmm22, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k1, xmm21, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm21 {k3}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddd  xmm22, xmm23, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k3, xmm22, xmm9
        vpaddq  ymm1, ymm1, ymm20
        vpaddq  ymm1, ymm30, ymm1
        vpblendmq       ymm20 {k4}, ymm11, ymm10
        kmovw   k4, word ptr [rsp - 26]         # 2-byte Reload
        vmovdqa64       ymm21 {k4}, ymm20
        vpaddq  ymm2, ymm2, ymm21
        vpblendmq       ymm20 {k6}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddq  ymm2, ymm29, ymm2
        vpblendmq       ymm21 {k1}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm20 {k2}, ymm21
        vpaddq  ymm16, ymm16, ymm20
        vpblendmq       ymm20 {k7}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddq  ymm16, ymm18, ymm16
        vpblendmq       ymm18 {k3}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm20 {k5}, ymm18
        vpaddq  ymm18, ymm19, ymm20
        vpaddq  ymm20, ymm17, ymm18
        vmovdqa xmm3, xmmword ptr [rsp - 24]    # 16-byte Reload
        vpcmpnleud      k2, xmm15, xmm3
        vpcmpnleud      k1, xmm0, xmm3
        kmovw   word ptr [rsp - 26], k1         # 2-byte Spill
        vpcmpltud       k4, xmm15, xmm5
        vpcmpltud       k3, xmm0, xmm5
        vpaddd  xmm15, xmm15, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k5, xmm15, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm15 {k4}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddd  xmm0, xmm8, xmm0
        vpcmpltud       k4, xmm0, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm0 {k5}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm0 {k2}, ymm15
        vpcmpnleud      k2, xmm13, xmm3
        vpcmpnleud      k5, xmm14, xmm3
        vpcmpltud       k6, xmm13, xmm5
        vpcmpltud       k7, xmm14, xmm5
        vpaddd  xmm13, xmm13, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k1, xmm13, xmm9
        vpblendmq       ymm13 {k3}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddd  xmm14, xmm14, xmm8
        vpcmpltud       k3, xmm14, xmm9
        vpaddq  ymm17, ymm1, ymm0
        vpblendmq       ymm0 {k4}, ymm11, ymm10
        kmovw   k4, word ptr [rsp - 26]         # 2-byte Reload
        vmovdqa64       ymm0 {k4}, ymm13
        vpblendmq       ymm1 {k6}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddq  ymm18, ymm2, ymm0
        vpblendmq       ymm0 {k1}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm0 {k2}, ymm1
        vpblendmq       ymm1 {k7}, ymm7, ymm6
        vpaddq  ymm19, ymm16, ymm0
        vpblendmq       ymm0 {k3}, ymm11, ymm10
        vmovdqa64       ymm0 {k5}, ymm1
        vpaddq  ymm20, ymm20, ymm0
        add     r9, 256
        add     r10, -16
        jne     .LBB1_8
```

This isn’t too bad: the compiler was able to turn `utf8_str_size<u32string>` into branchless vectorized code using the full-width registers.  You can see that sometimes it has to fall back on 128-bit instead of 256-bit instructions, and sometimes it runs out of registers and needs to spill.

Using Toby Speight’s version as the transformation function gives us this output instead:

```
.LBB1_8:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovdqu ymm12, ymmword ptr [rax - 64]
        vmovdqu ymm13, ymmword ptr [rax - 32]
        vmovdqu ymm11, ymmword ptr [rax]
        vmovdqu ymm14, ymmword ptr [rax + 32]
        vmovdqa64       ymm17, ymm12
        vmovdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_0] # xmm0 = [0,4,8,12]
        vpermt2d        ymm17, ymm0, ymm13
        vmovdqa64       ymm18, ymm11
        vpermt2d        ymm18, ymm0, ymm14
        vmovdqa64       ymm19, ymm12
        vmovdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_1] # xmm0 = [1,5,9,13]
        vpermt2d        ymm19, ymm0, ymm13
        vmovdqa64       ymm20, ymm11
        vpermt2d        ymm20, ymm0, ymm14
        vmovdqa ymm15, ymm12
        vmovdqa xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_2] # xmm0 = [2,6,10,14]
        vpermt2d        ymm15, ymm0, ymm13
        vmovdqa64       ymm16, ymm11
        vpermt2d        ymm16, ymm0, ymm14
        vpermt2d        ymm12, ymm3, ymm13
        vpermt2d        ymm11, ymm3, ymm14
        vpcmpnleud      k1, xmm17, xmm4
        vpblendmq       ymm13 {k1}, ymm6, ymm5
        vpcmpnleud      k1, xmm18, xmm4
        vpblendmq       ymm14 {k1}, ymm6, ymm5
        vpcmpnleud      k1, xmm19, xmm4
        vpblendmq       ymm21 {k1}, ymm6, ymm5
        vpcmpnleud      k1, xmm20, xmm4
        vpblendmq       ymm22 {k1}, ymm6, ymm5
        vpcmpnleud      k1, xmm15, xmm4
        vpblendmq       ymm23 {k1}, ymm6, ymm5
        vpcmpnleud      k1, xmm16, xmm4
        vpblendmq       ymm24 {k1}, ymm6, ymm5
        vpcmpnleud      k1, xmm12, xmm4
        vpblendmq       ymm25 {k1}, ymm6, ymm5
        vpcmpnleud      k1, xmm11, xmm4
        vpblendmq       ymm26 {k1}, ymm6, ymm5
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm17, xmm7
        vpmovm2q        ymm27, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm18, xmm7
        vpmovm2q        ymm28, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm17, xmm8
        vpmovm2q        ymm17, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm18, xmm8
        vpmovm2q        ymm18, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm19, xmm7
        vpmovm2q        ymm29, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm20, xmm7
        vpmovm2q        ymm30, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm19, xmm8
        vpmovm2q        ymm19, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm20, xmm8
        vpmovm2q        ymm20, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm15, xmm7
        vpmovm2q        ymm31, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm16, xmm7
        vpmovm2q        ymm0, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm15, xmm8
        vpmovm2q        ymm15, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm16, xmm8
        vpmovm2q        ymm16, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm12, xmm7
        vpmovm2q        ymm1, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm11, xmm7
        vpmovm2q        ymm2, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm12, xmm8
        vpmovm2q        ymm12, k0
        vpcmpnleud      k0, xmm11, xmm8
        vpmovm2q        ymm11, k0
        vpsubq  ymm9, ymm9, ymm27
        vpaddq  ymm9, ymm9, ymm13
        vpsubq  ymm10, ymm10, ymm28
        vpaddq  ymm10, ymm10, ymm14
        vpsubq  ymm9, ymm9, ymm17
        vpsubq  ymm10, ymm10, ymm18
        vpsubq  ymm9, ymm9, ymm29
        vpaddq  ymm9, ymm9, ymm21
        vpsubq  ymm10, ymm10, ymm30
        vpaddq  ymm10, ymm10, ymm22
        vpsubq  ymm9, ymm9, ymm19
        vpsubq  ymm10, ymm10, ymm20
        vpsubq  ymm9, ymm9, ymm31
        vpaddq  ymm9, ymm9, ymm23
        vpsubq  ymm0, ymm10, ymm0
        vpaddq  ymm0, ymm0, ymm24
        vpsubq  ymm9, ymm9, ymm15
        vpsubq  ymm0, ymm0, ymm16
        vpsubq  ymm1, ymm9, ymm1
        vpaddq  ymm1, ymm1, ymm25
        vpsubq  ymm0, ymm0, ymm2
        vpaddq  ymm0, ymm0, ymm26
        vpsubq  ymm9, ymm1, ymm12
        vpsubq  ymm10, ymm0, ymm11
        sub     rax, -128
        add     r10, -8
        jne     .LBB1_8
```

This version needs fewer instructions inside the same loop (unrolled to operate on 32 words per iteration).  Because it uses registers more efficiently, it does not need to spill any onto the stack. The additions are again transformed into subtractions, but this time, it’s because the vector comparisons turn `true` into the bitmask `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is `-1L`.

Finally, a [link to the code on Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/4dxfr7nG7)

Comment: Very informative, but it seems you did not want to explicitly time things (understandably). Maybe a bit more story would have made it even nicer.

Comment: @JoopEggen Find some extremely large multilingual text? And by extremely large, I mean vectorized code like this will breeze through megabytes in milliseconds, so time a loop that runs them a thousand or a million times.

Comment: @JoopEggen And if you want it to be really fast, add an execution policy of `std::execution::par`, or rewrite as a loop with `#pragma omp parallel for simd`, to enable both vectorization and multithreading. For best results, use ICX with `-fiopenmp`

Comment: Probably better to use `<cstdint>` and `<cstddef>` rather than the C versions of these headers (despite the implications of the code presented for review).  The only valid use for the C headers is in header files to be included into programs written in both languages.

Comment: Thanks greatly for providing such detailed analysis, especially of my answer that I wrote really quickly.

Comment: @TobySpeight I think you’re right about the headers, here. I often use `<stdint.h>` and `<stddef.h>` in my own code, mainly because that was how I had been using them for years when `<cstddef>` and `<cstdint>` were added. It saves me several `using` directives. However, a template like this would normally go in a header file. And we should never import from `std::` in header files. There is also the very remote possibility that some insane person will add an identifier to the C headers that conflicts with one of ours.